# Where is '__find_end' present in Visual Studio 19 C/C++ Development Tools?

Tags: c++, windows, include

I was trying to compile an old code, and received the following error:

error G1A4676F8: no member named '`__find_end`' in namespace 'std'

I searched online and found it is defined in stl_algo.h, which I couldn't find in my Windows system. Also, the documentations were of libstdc++4 and earlier.

The code compiles fine on https://godbolt.org/ with all MSVC versions.

The include statements are:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
```

The compiler shows an alternative as find_end defined in algorithm but I am not sure if __find_end has the same functionality as find_end.

So, my question is, is `__find_end` deprecated? 
If not, where can I find it's declaration in Windows? 
If yes, what are my alternatives? Is `find_end` a perfect substitute for `__find_end`?

Comment: All names starting with `__` are reserved for internal compiler use. So it's not a question of being deprecated, it should never have been used in the first place.

Comment: The code is a part of a compiler itself. It's being used to define some string functions like __str_rfind

Comment: You're trying to port the g++ compiler to windows? That has been done before.

Comment: Just a clarification about terminology: the "Windows SDK" is a bunch of libraries for high-level interactions with Windows (SDK stands for Software Development Kit). It supports creating windows on the display screen, looping input events (mouse clicks, keyboard actions), etc. It's **not** the C++ standard library; that comes with your **compiler**. And it's not the support code that the C++ standard library uses; that, too, comes with your compiler.

Comment: I hope the question makes more sense now.